# ミスTapした時、範囲外にドラッグしてから離すキャンセル（タッチイベント無効にさせたい）

Tags: android, java

誤ってタップしたとき、ドラッグしてから離しキャンセルさせたい場合
タッチイベントをスルーするにはどのうようにするのでしょうか？
普通ならClickListenerだけを使えば済むのですが、タッチイベントも実装したいです

下の場合は範囲外で離しても処理123を実行してしまいます
通常は処理1,2だけ実行、キャンセルの時だけ処理3をしたい
（本プログラムではACTION_MOVEが入っています）

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // 処理.1
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // 処理.2
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    // 処理.3
}
```

タッチイベント内のswitch文をif文で大きく括りfalseならswitch処理させない
では出来そうですが、皆様はどうやってるのでしょうか
またClickListenerを実装しないやり方はあるのでしょうか

宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 1):

私なら処理をonTouchだけに統一し、処理２の中をifで分岐させます。

処理１、及び処理２で event.getX()、event.getY()を使用し、タップされた時と離された時の位置を取得します。そして処理２でタップの有効範囲（これは事前に計算しておく）とこれらを比較し、有効なら処理２、範囲外なら処理３を実行するようにします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ロケーションを比較させ出来ました。クリックリスナー実装でも出来ましたが、言われる通りタッチリスナーだけの方がスマートで分かりやすいですね。